# How can I migrate from Hangouts to the new Chat?

Tags: google-hangouts, google-chat

Some of my contacts have migrated to the new Google Chat which means now I need it installed. Some of my conversations were automatically migrated to Chat but some were not and others have trickled over slowly. I would like to uninstall Hangouts to not have double notifications but I can't quite get there because some group chats in Hangouts have not migrated to Chat so if I uninstall I will lose access to those chats.

I have this notification in Chat

> You can only join chats and rooms that you were invited to.

[image: You can only join chats and rooms that you were invited to.]

At first I thought "duh, I can never join a chat I wasn't invited to. This isn't new, why are they telling me this?" But now I see that I can't actually create any new chats at all with existing contacts. There is a random assortment of one-on-one chats migrated, group chats (which appear in the one-on-one chats section of Chat) and group chats which migrated over as "Rooms" but no way to create a new one of any of these.

How can I have one messaging app (at least for my Google contacts) again?

Comment: I closed this questions because nowadays https://hangouts.google.com redirects to https://mail.google.com/chat/

Answer (score 0):

As of April 29, 2023 the first link included below shows the following notice

> Google Hangouts has been upgraded to Google Chat. Learn about the switch from Google Hangouts to Google Chat.

The last statement is a link that points to the same page.

---

##### Original answer

From [The latest on Google Hangouts and the upgrade to Google Chat](https://blog.google/products/workspace/latest-google-hangouts-and-upgrade-google-chat/) published on October 15, 2020

> Starting in the first half of 2021, everyone can begin upgrading from Hangouts to Chat.

As of today (January, 30 of 21), it might be too soon for Google common accounts (i.e. accounts having a `@gmail.com` email address). If you have a G Suite (not yet updated as Google Workspace) or Google Workspace account, please contact your organization admin.

Related

- [Use Google Chat and classic Hangouts together](https://support.google.com/chat/answer/7651799?hl=en) (Official Google Chat Help article)